# After adding ExtensionInstallSources preference with my URL to Chrome Preferences, still won't allow installing ".crx" packaged app

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I added the preference `ExtensionInstallSources` (as per: http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources ), it still is not allowing me to install my "app.crx" from my URL. I added it as follows:

**File: /home/myuser/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences**

```
"extensions": {
    "ExtensionInstallSources": [ "http://myurl.com/*" ],
...elided...
```

Yet, when I go to the url `http://myurl.com/myapp/app.crx` it tells me it cannot install from that url. How do I fix this?

### **MORE INFO:**

It appears that `Preferences` file is not the correct one to edit. I downloaded an example on from here: http://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip as specified here: http://support.google.com/chrome/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=187945

That provides a "chrome.json" file **but does not specify where to install this**. I tried installing it in the `.config/chrome/Default` folder but that doesn't work.

My chrome.js file is:

```
// Policy template for Linux.
// Uncomment the policies you wish to activate and change their values to
// something useful for your case. The provided values are for reference only
// and do not provide meaningful defaults!
{
    "ExtensionInstallSources": ["http://myurl.lamp/*"]
}
```

It still does not work!

### **2ND UPDATE:**

I put the setting in `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/test_policy.json` as specified here: http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start and it **still does not work**!

### **3RD UPDATE:**

I checked `chrome://policy` and it shows the permission is there! It still won't let me install crx's from the URL though! It shows the value for `ExtensionInstallSources` is:

```
http://myurl.lamp/*,http://localhost/*,http://192.168.1.109/*,*://myurl.lamp/*,file:///*
```

But none of those work!

Comment: @sowbug I saw you updated this post. Can you offer any ideas for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this using chrome unstable (35.0.1908.4) in a test ubuntu virtual machine and it worked fine. Did you restart chrome after changing the policy file?