# Load unpacked Chrome extension programmatically

Tags: shell, google-chrome, command-line, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to load and unload unpacked Chrome extensions from the Command Line?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, although only temporarily *:

```
chromium --load-extension=path/to/extension
```

If you want to load multiple extensions, just separate the path by a comma:

```
chromium --load-extension=path/to/extension,path/to/another/extension
```

Replace `chromium` with `chrome.exe` (or whatever is used to start your Chrome/Chromium browser).

* When you close the browser, and starts it again *without* the command line argument, then the extension will disappear from the list of installed extensions.

Comment: I should have clarified my question, I wanted to do so while chrome is running.

Comment: `chrome --load-extension=path/to/extension` is not working. Any ideas? I'm on windows

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan Try `\` instead of `/`.

Comment: @RobW what did you mean by ` insted of/`

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan Backslash instead of forward slash, i.e. `--load-extension=path\to\extension`.

Comment: Oh, i tried that. No luck with that command, but I found solution in my below answer

Comment: @eldos Edit your shortcut and put the flag in the parameters.

Comment: not working with multiple paths split with commas for me - is there a way to load multiple extensions?

Comment: @wildeyes, 9 years later this is how I did it: `sudo pkill -a -i "Google Chrome" && open -na "Google Chrome" --args --load-extension=/path/to/extension--restore-last-session`. I'm just restarting chrome and restoring the session.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to install using `--load-and-launch-app=path/to/app`

it is working for both apps and extensions. (I tested on chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m)

I am not sure that there is another command for uninstalling. I found [this list of chromium commands](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) which is very useful.

Comment: This flag does not permanently install an app or extension. Once the flag is removed, the extension/app is gone as well. `--load-and-launch-app` and `--load-extension` should both [work as expected](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/unpacked_installer.h?revision=282250&view=markup#l44). I think that you had at least one Chrome window open when you tried to use the `--load-extension` flag. These flags are only functional if Chrome is completely shut down.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just close all windows of chrome and run that command then extension is loaded. Then i close chrome and launch it again. Extension is there. Any how i don't know the reason.

Comment: Open the task manager and check for any open chrome.exe processes.

Comment: I did after you told that, ya there were chrome.exe processes, is it the reson? I kill all processes and launch chrome again, still there is extension installed from above command.

Comment: Kill all processes, and start chrome.exe without these command line flags. Then the extension/app will not be installed. If it is installed, then you have probably loaded the extension as an unpacked extension before via the "Load unpacked extension" button at `chrome://extensions` in developer mode.

Comment: You are right, I used that command for install unpacked extension, and developer mode is on. i think that is the case. I followed your steps after removing previously installed extension but i am getting same result. Any how i'll change answer. thanks

Comment: --load-and-launch-app works also while chrome is running and even better it doesn't even open a chrome window afterwards if you loaded an extension .. perfect for automation during extension development

Comment: no longer works in chrome 79 / chromium 79. Received an error message asking me to use `--load-extension=` instead

Answer (score 5):

**3 ways install/use Chrome extensions offline:**

---

**Method A:** Drag & Drop (Simple)

- Drag & drop ABP.crx on: chrome://extensions to install

**Pros:** Installs web & non-westore extensions

**Cons:** Google quickly & permanently disables non-webstore extensions

---

**Method B:** Load unzipped extension/7zip to unzip/ABP used as example

- UnZip ABP.crx: C:\ABP
- Load 1: Shortcut: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-extension="C:\ABP"
- Load 2: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-extension="C:\ABP,C:\IEtab"

**Pros:** Permanently enables non-webstore extensions, so long as your using custom shortcut

**Cons:** Extensions only load via custom shortcut

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 3 fixes for extracted extension errors: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

- Won't load: Create shortcut to folder containing manifest file, for example:
  akkmfdhlogbapbcgojknhfgppcionopk\5.4.7_0
- Metadata: Extension\delete _metadata folder
- Disabled: Open manifest.json with notepad & locate:

"name": "**MSG_appName**",

"offline_enabled": true,

Create: "offline_enabled": true, if it doesn't exist

---

**Method C:** WinRar SFX (Mass install local/non-local profile apps)

Chrome extracts all plugins to:
%LocalAppData%\Google\User Data\Default\Extensions

Extensions list by web-store ID. Example: ABP=cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb

ABP needs 3 files: Some extensions may only require 2

- Install all plugins needed, remove all not needed. Exit Chrome.
- Backup: %LocalAppData%\Google to: C:\Backup\Google
- Copy: %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions to: C:\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
- Copy: %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\secure preferences to: C:\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\secure preferences
- Copy: %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings to: C:\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings
- Create WinRar SFX: Extract C:\Google to: %LocalAppData%\Google

(ABP stores settings: %LocalAppData%\Google\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings)

**Pros:** Mass install web & non-webstore apps, from local/nonlocal pc's

**Cons:** Google quickly & permanently disables non-webstore extensions

When SFX imports secure preferences file, it replaces old extensions/settings with imported

**Restore Chrome Backup:**

- Exit Chrome & delete %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome
- Copy C:\Backup\Google to: %LocalAppData%\Google
- Launch Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I took the [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784332/8706090) and got the perfect script for me on mac.

I want just to share with you

```
open -a chromium --args --load-extension=$PWD/build --force-dev-mode-highlighting --no-default-browser-check
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill all existing instances of Chrome from task manager : `TASKKILL /IM chrome.exe /F` and then `chrome.exe --load-extension=path/to/extension` should work

This working C# code for console application can help

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process cmd = new Process();

            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            cmd.Start();
            //kill all chrome instances
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("TASKKILL /IM chrome.exe /F");
            //path to chrome.exe
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application");
            //load extension
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("chrome.exe --load-extension={path-to-extension}");

            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

        }
    }
```