# Load unpacked Chrome Extension from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can I somehow Load an Unpacked Chrome extension to Chrome within the JavaScript code from another extension?

Comment: No, it's [not possible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management).

Comment: Although, you can do it from command line:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782557/load-unpacked-chrome-extension-programmatically

Comment: Is a way to load it from an extension?