# UndetectedChromedriver Extension Issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I can't use extensions on UndetectedChromedriver PYPI Package (Python). If I use it with normal selenium its works, but not with this package. I tried to install extensions directly from webstore, but Chrome Webstore Alert is not an Alert to handle with selenium is a Window Event, so we need to use AutoIT, Pyautogui, etc... To handle that.

The only thing is working is loading profiles, but... I'm working for multiprocess windows, is working, but I need to create houndred of windows and then delete them. And I can't clone profiles, because UndetectedChromedriver doesn't work, i need to create manually.

Finally i tried with Google Chrome Enterprise Bundle, then I used Extensions policy to install forced the extension for all profiles. And yes, is working, but if I enabled that, selenium, doesn't work properly.

The error traceback log is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\envs\selenium-env\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\envs\selenium-env\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Documentos\(A1)_Inicio\(A2)_CyberEspacio\LAB\(A1)_Programador123\(A1)_Programming_(Section)\VSCode Snippets\python\selenium\app.py", line 72, in test
    seleniumCaptchaSolver.reCaptchaServiceLogin(apiKey='MYAPIKEY', solverType = SeleniumCaptchaSolverType().Capmonster)
  File "C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Documentos\(A1)_Inicio\(A2)_CyberEspacio\LAB\(A1)_Programador123\(A1)_Programming_(Section)\VSCode Snippets\python\selenium\modules\seleniumCaptchaSolver.py", line 103, in reCaptchaServiceLogin
    self.__driver.get('chrome-extension://pabjfbciaedomjjfelfafejkppknjleh/popup.html')
  File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\envs\selenium-env\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 535, in get
    return super().get(url)
  File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\envs\selenium-env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 447, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\envs\selenium-env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\envs\selenium-env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response   
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

This happen only when chrome-extension://pabjfbciaedomjjfelfafejkppknjleh/popup.html is opened to login (Send APi Key). I can login etc... But when Policy is Activated I can't because of that issue.

Anyone here know how to fix that or properly use extensions in UndetctedChromedriver?

Note: This error only happens if i load chrome-extension://pabjfbciaedomjjfelfafejkppknjleh/popup.html link, others links works.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import os

working_dir = os.getcwd()
# Im using proxy extension
proxy_plugin = f'{working_dir}/proxy_plugin'

options = uc.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument(f'--load-extension={proxy_plugin}')
# {proxy_plugin} path to extension folder, I tried to import .zip file
# and this doesnt working, maybe you can try import .crx file

# Also, I use extensions.ui.developer_mode
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', { 'extensions.ui.developer_mode': True })

driver = uc.Chrome(options = options)
```

[extensions.ui.developer_mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqqvR.png)

Yet, I seen this pages:

[Load unpacked Chrome extension programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782557/load-unpacked-chrome-extension-programmatically)

[Installing extension into V2](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/349)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).