# Chromium | add extension file (.crx) without GUI (via ssh)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I have extension file.
I want install it for all my users of linux server.

Something like this

```
[root@srv]# su - user1
[user1@srv]$ chromium-browser --install-ext-from-file-foo-bar /path/to/ext.crx
```

It is available? or drag-and-drop method only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800696/how-install-crx-chrome-extension-via-command-line

Answer (score 0):

For Linux specifically, the method [described in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#preferences) should work, at least for now.

It consists of placing a specific manifest file in `/opt/google/chrome/extensions/` or
`/usr/share/google-chrome/extensions/`

Note that it *is* installing it for all users indiscriminately.

Also note that this will still allow any user to uninstall the extension, which will blacklist it for a particular profile unless reinstalled manually.