# Why is my packaged chrome extension not updating?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, google-chrome-app

**UPDATE: Solved one part, but not other**

1. I have the CRX updating now (it was not rebuilding).
2. **However**, Chrome will not accept the XML or CRX at an https URL.

I believe #2 is because it's a self-signed certificate. Does anyone know if there's a way around this? (This is purely for development, so hosted internally)

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I created a packaged extension that is hosted on my internal website, but is added to Chrome via dragging it from the desktop (because Chrome won't allow installing packaged extensions via external websites - see here: [After adding ExtensionInstallSources preference with my URL to Chrome Preferences, still won't allow installing ".crx" packaged app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489013/after-adding-extensioninstallsources-preference-with-my-url-to-chrome-preference) ).

The manifest has the `update_url` set to an XML file located on my site. That XML file has the url for the crx file set under `updatecheck codebase='...'`. Both files exist on the website and are findable. I also upated the version number from `2.0.0.2` to `2.0.0.2` in both the XML file and the `manifest.json`. I also made a change in the index.html file of the extension.

I checked the `appid` and it is the same in the XML file and in Chrome.

Despite clicking the "update extensions now" button about 50 times, and waiting 10 minutes, it does not update.

*NOTE: I did alias the internal ip 192.168.1.108 where the site is hosted in my hosts file as `myinternal.fake` but this works in both chrome and firefox so I don't think that's the issue*

**Update XML File (located at: https://myinternal.fake/updates/helloworld.xml)**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
    <app appid='akchdaojnpiglpjeiamjpacbkppcgbgj'>
        <updatecheck codebase='https://myinternal.fake/helloworld.crx' version='2.0.0.2' prodversionmin='23' />
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Hello World",
    "version": "2.0.0.2",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "update_url": "https://myinternal.fake/updates/helloworld.xml",
    "icons": 
    {
        "16": "icon_16.png",
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "app": 
    {
        "background": 
        {
            "scripts": 
            [
                "main.js"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I also checked and the header is an acceptable one for Chrome (according to this: http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/hosting.html). It sends the CRX file as "text/plain" and does NOT send the header `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` so it should be valid.

Also, when I changed from `https` to `http`, now when I click "update extensions now" the extension disappears for a split second which indicates it's now reading the XML, but still not accepting the update!

Comment: Does your code just updates, or also installs your chrome extension? I can see get request in my server console but it does not install?

Comment: @BarisLaPaz You should post your own question if you have one. This post is from 4 years ago and Chrome has changed a lot of the rules and architecture for chrome extensions since then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with self-signed certificates and Chrome. Chrome does not accept Extension updates form self-signed certificates unless they're an "accepted" authority. These steps will make it work:

1. Follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15076602/857025 to export your certificate and then import it as an authority
2. Close Chrome
3. Restart Chrome
4. Close extensions window if opened
5. Reopen via "chrome://extensions" and then click "update extensions now"

It should then update your extension located on a self-signed https connection.

**UPDATE** This is not a perfect solution as Chrome appears to be a bit wonky in accepting self-signed certs. It randomly stops seeing updates. If I switch back to using regular http (for the update_url and the CRX's url), updates happen every time.

I checked and my cert is still a trusted authority but Chrome suddenly stopped recognizing updates, so there must be an issue with this.

Answer (score 2):

By the way Google Stopped supporting updating extensions that are hosted outside of Chrome Webstore: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html